# How can Angular Service Function return response to controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

Actually, I am uploading image using service, image uploaded successfully, but I want responded data to the function in controller.

Controller:

```
adminApp.controller('imageController', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', 'Images',function ($scope, fileUpload, Images) {

$scope.uploadFile = function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var file = data.myFile;
    console.log('file is ');
    console.dir(file);
    var uploadUrl = "/image";
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, data, uploadUrl);
    // $scope.images.push();

  };
}]);
```

Service:

```
adminApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {

this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, data, uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('owner_id', data.owner_id);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            // return data;
        })
        .error(function () {
        });
  }
}]);
```

laravel (backhand):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('file');
    $image = $this->imageRepository->makeImage($image);
    return $image;
}
```

I function in service return responded data from backhand to controller, so I can push the value to `$scope.images` in controllers function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of angular `$q` here.

Updated Service Function

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, data, uploadUrl) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('owner_id', data.owner_id);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            // return data;
           defer.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            defer.reject(error);
        });
  }

return defer.promise;

}]);
```

In your controller, you can use the function as

```
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, data, uploadUrl).then(function(response){

    //response contains your data form service

}).catch(function(error){

    // error variable contains error data from service.

});
```

the code is not tested.. but it should work or very close.

Comment: Showing error,  angular.min.js:92 TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

Comment: In your service, you need to include defer `adminApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q)`

Comment: included then after showing, **TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined**

Comment: would you please explain me, $q, defer and promise?, Thanks

Comment: You can read on [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) - A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done the processing. $q is an angular implementation of Javascript Promise.